# Playing No Agenda HD on Apple iTunes through Amazon Alexa

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo, audio, machine-learning

Periodically, I'll [try to listen to a podcast](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/5095/1042) with `Alexa` yet always get the same poor result.  Until today.

Now, it plays [something](https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/no-agenda-ep-5-summer-catch-up/id1204526555?i=1000381025154) called "no agenda ep.5" from Apple iTunes.  Which is perplexing in a few ways. Firstly, I would expect `Alexa` to use `TuneIn`, and, secondly, I cannot even figure out what podcast it is playing. Finally, if that command plays podcast x through iTunes, how do I play podcast x1?  Here:  No Agenda.

Perhaps just [use](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/12/16/amazons-alexa-can-now-play-apple-podcasts-on-echo-devices) iTunes?  Although I prefer the voice interface commands Alexa offers via TuneIn over, for example, AnyPod. I certainly never enabled iTunes, but Amazon just adding that on their own seems par for the course.

---

Actually, as linked above:

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/no-agenda-ep-5-summer-catch-up/id1204526555?i=1000381025154

which points to:

https://soundcloud.com/noagendapodcast/no-agenda-ep5-summer-catch-up

it seems to be playing an episode from four years ago!?  I didn't even recognize it as the same podcast.

Also, I came across an Alexa skill, "no agenda", which gives the option to listen to the live stream (quite useful) or to play the latest episode.  It's sub-par as a podcast player, but is useful if only for the live stream.